# Present continuous vs Present perfect continuous

Tags: meaning, differences, present-tense, perfect-aspect, continuous-aspect

1. I am waiting for you for almost an hour
2. I have been waiting for you for almost an hour

What's the difference? Are both OK?

Comment: Either way, someone's in big trouble.

Comment: Could you please say what *you* think is the answer, and why. Could you please say why ignored: (1) "I have waited for you for almost an hour" which uses the present perfect tense. Or (2) "I will be waiting for you for almost an hour" Or, (3) "I shall be waiting for you for almost an hour". What is the context for this sentence?

Comment: _I am waiting for <someone> for <a time>_ is not idiomatic, and marks the speaker out as a non-native speaker. (There's a slight exception to this: there is one fairly unusual case where it would be used, referring to an intention in the immediate future: _I am waiting here for an hour, and if he hasn't come I shall give up and go home_. This is unlikely to be used with _you_ or for an "almost" time).

Answer (score 1):

The first uses the imperfect progressive tense, which expresses an ongoing present action; it is used to answer the question, *what is happening now?* "I am singing"; "I am waiting"; "I am going." The second is the perfect progressive tense, which expresses an action that began in the past and which has continued to the present moment; it is used to answer the question, *what has been happening?* or *What have you been doing?* This is the one you want to use: "I have been singing for some time now"; "*I have been waiting for you for almost an hour*"; "I have been going there for three weeks." It's true that both of these tenses describe an ongoing action (they are both in the present tense), but only the perfect progressive is used to indicate that the action in question has a history. ("Imperfect" in this sense means continuing, not complete; "perfect" means complete. When you tell someone that you have been waiting for an hour, you are saying that, up until the moment you utter this sentence, you have waited an hour; this a completed action--which does not mean you won't continue waiting, but, if you *do* continue waiting, it will no longer be true that you have waited only an hour.)